# How to load an AnimatorSet with animations defined in xml

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to play several animations in a row, one after the other. These animations will be either simple transforms (moving imageviews a certain distance) or more complex frame animations.

In researching the issue, AnimatorSet seemed to be a good solution at first. It allows you to make a queue of animations to be played, and then execute them in a particular order.

```
    // defining an example animation
    Animator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "alpha", 0f)
            .setDuration(100);
    AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();

    // dictating the order in which the animations will be played
    set.playSequentially(anim, skewAnim, wobbleAnim);

    set.start();
```

The issue is that, as far as I can tell, you cannot define an Animator object to put in the AnimatorSet from an animation which is defined in an xml file.

Also, AnimationSet (notice different name) only allows you to play several animations all at once, so this class would not work for my purposes.

Does anybody know of a way to define an Animator object from an xml object in your project? Alternatively, is there possibly another way to go about playing a sequence of animations altogether?

UPDATE:

```
    AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
    Animator anim1 = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getApplicationContext(), R.animator.sample);
    anim1.setTarget(myView1);
    Animator anim2 = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getApplicationContext(), R.animator.sample);
    anim2.setTarget(myView2);

    anim1.setDuration(3000);
    anim2.setDuration(3000);

    anim1.setInterpolator(new CycleInterpolator(5));
    anim2.setInterpolator(new CycleInterpolator(5));

    set.playSequentially(anim1,anim2);
    set.start();
```

Answer (score 3):

To load animations into AnimatorSet from xml, your xml should contain AnimatorObjects and not animations. Then you can use AnimatorInflater to load those animatorObjects into your AnimatorSet like this:

```
AnimatorSet set = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getActivity(), R.animator.sample);
```

xml would like something like this:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:ordering="sequentially"
    >

  <objectAnimator
      android:propertyName="alpha"
      android:duration="500"
      android:valueTo="1f"
      />
  <objectAnimator
    android:propertyName="y"
    android:duration="500"
    android:valueTo="300"
    android:valueType="intType"/>
</set>
```

Refer this link for more detail on [AnimatorInflater](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorInflater.html)

For playing sequential animations on different views you can use AnimationListeners.

```
anim1.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                             // start anim2 from here
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                            }});
```

Comment: Thank you Ravinder. Would you have any idea why my animator set is not playing the animations as would be expected? (see edits above)

Comment: if you provide multiple animator objects into single xml and use it to create AnimatorSet the way I've mentioned above than those animations would be played according to the ordering specifiec in xml file. But from above update i can see that you wan't to play sequential animations on different views, for that you need animation listeners, check my answer